# Why do I have 4 partitions?

Tags: partitioning, operating-systems

I wanted to install another OS on my laptop but I noticed that I already have 4 partitions the first is Healthy EFI Partition then Recovery then C: then Restore Partition. Should I remove one? If so which one? Can I have 5 partitions using AOMEI Partition Assistant? What should I do?

Comment: If you have a newer laptop with GPT partitioned disk then the 4 partition limit does not apply.

Comment: GPT drives must contain at least 128 partition entries, so you don't need to worry, unless you need more than 128 partitions then you might need to resize the GPT metadata

Comment: Better post a screenshot of the Disk Management screen to get a fair idea of your current partition scheme. It appears that you do not have any free space and all the available space is occupied by your C:. Yon can Shrink this Volume from within DIsk Management Console (Assuming space is available on it) to create free space and then proceed with installation of another OS onto it (In a Dual Boot Configuration) if you do not want to disturb current Windows installation.

Comment: Even a MBR partition table can have more than 4 partitions, just one of the 4 primary partitions has to be an extended partition, that contains a lot more partitions. Did you try creating another partition in the remaining free space? With gparted?

Comment: You should avoid deleting any of the partitions you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why you have four partitions is:

- The EFI partition is used to store files used by UEFI
- Recovery and restore are used
  to hold system files needed when performing for example a factory
  reset.
- The C: partition is your (and the operating systems) primary partition used for storage.

This makes it possible to load UEFI at boot, and also to replace your current installation with a brand new one without the need of installation CD:s or externally loaded images.